Who added the phrase "Salah is better than sleep" to the Fajar azan?
I am a bit confused. 1) someone mentioned that these phrases salah is better then sleep were added by umar ibn khattab after Prophet PBUH time and somewhere else it is mentioned with references that hazrat Bilal R.A was adviced by Prophet PBUH to add these phrases only in fajar azaan and not in all the azans like he used too.
So I want to know

if Prophet PBUH was alive and well when these phrases were added in Azan

and that were these phrases added by Prophet SAW himself due to Hazrat Umar bin Khattab incident.??




(referening to the incident I read where someone said these phrases were added by Umar bin Khattab after Prophet PBUH time when: once when he R.A himself slept through fajar azan and azan reciter came to wake him up and said these phrases and was then asked to add these in every fajar azan for the muslims.)



or were these phrases asked to be added by  Umar Bin Khattab (in relation to above mentioned incident) after Prophet SAW's time.??


It was prescribed by the Prophet ﵌ during his lifetime.

عن أبي محذورة، قال كنت أؤذن لرسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم وكنت أقول في أذان الفجر الأول حى على الفلاح الصلاة خير من النوم الصلاة خير من النوم الله أكبر الله أكبر لا إله إلا الله
It was narrated that Abu Mahdhurah said:
"I used to call the Adhan for the Messenger of Allah (﵌) and in the first Adhan of Fajr I used to Say: 'Hayya 'ala al-falah, as-salatu khairun minan-nawm, as-salatu khairun minan-nawm, Allahu Akbar Allahu Akbar, la ilaha illallah (Come to prosperity, prayer is better than sleep, prayer is better than sleep, Allah is the Greatest, Allah is the Greatest, there is none worthy of worship except Allah).'"
— Nasai


عن سويد بن غفلة: أنه أرسل إلى مؤذنه: إذا بلغت: حي على الفلاح، فقل: الصلاة خير من النوم، فإنه أذان بلال
Suwaid bin Ghafalah sent a message to his muezzin: When you reach 'Hayya 'ala al-falah' (Hasten to success), say: 'As-salatu khairun min an-nawm' (Prayer is better than sleep), for it was in the adhan of Bilal.
— Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaybah


عن أنس قال:  من السنة إذا قال المؤذن في أذان الفجر: حي على الفلاح قال: الصلاة خير من النوم
Anas said: "It is from the Sunnah that when the Mu'adhadhin says in the Adhan of Fajr: Haiya 'alal-Falah (Come to the success), he also says as-Salatu khairun minan-nawm (Prayer is better than sleep)."
— Saheeh Ibn Khuzaimah

There does exist a report that can suggest that it was added by Umar, but that is considered weak or given alternate interpretations.
